# NHibernate: How to delete a set of objects?

Tags: nhibernate

Let's say that we have 100 objects of type User and each user has a one-to-one reference. The batch size in NHibernate config is set to 50. So, if we delete all 100 objects NHibernate will fire 200 connections to the DB. I want to delete them with 4 connection with 50 queries in each connection. The code below is a copy/paste from my batch insert methods which works as expected:

```
public void BatchDelete(IEnumerable<T> entitiesToDelete)
    {
        int batchSzie = Session.GetSessionImplementation().Batcher.BatchSize;
        int batchedInsertsCount = 0;
        foreach (var entity in entitiesToDelete)
        {
            batchedInsertsCount++;
            Session.Delete(entity);
            if (batchedInsertsCount % batchSzie == 0)
            {
                Session.Flush();
                Session.Clear();
            }
        }
    }
```

EDIT: I forgot to mention that I am in a transaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you are not setting the batch size for the session (session.BatchSize()) so it will use what ever is the default or what you have configured when sessionfactory is created. But more importantly there is no support for batch deletes. Even if you would set the session.BatchSize() correctly it has no effect (at least with NHibernate 3.2 and SQL Server 2008). [Ayende has a blog post that shows how to solve the problem](http://ayende.com/blog/1294/bulk-data-operations-using-nhibernate).

Comment: !0x Toni. I also read that article but it was written in 2006 so I thought it is fixed in 2011. May be there is a reason for not doing batch deletes.

Answer (score 5):

```
            Session.Flush();
            Session.Clear();
```

Normally indicates you are doing something wrong, start adding transactions and remove the:

```
if (batchedInsertsCount % batchSzie == 0)
```

A different approach can be a query with a delete and in:

```
            // fill batch with id list of items you want to delete
            _session.CreateQuery(String.Format("DELETE  FROM TABLENAME WHERE Id IN (:idsList)", _domainObject.Name))
                    .SetParameterList("idsList", batch.ToArray())
                    .ExecuteUpdate();
```

Make sure you check for 2100 max ids, that is the max for parameters you can give to sqlserver.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am in a transaction. Why flush/clear is bad thing? Flush is pretty useful when dealing with deletes before inserts for example. Anyway, after removing flush/clear I still got 200 connections. :|

Comment: The need for a Session.Flush(); normally indicates (in most cases) that something is not right in a code review. If you delete like you do in your sample code you will send 200 queries to the database. The queries will be send in batches of 50 queries, that is you batch size. Flushing will not change that. What you can do is make a custom delete query to delete all records in 1 query: 
                _session.CreateQuery(

Comment: The String.Format statement used around the DELETE statement can't be useful here? It has no "{0}"?

Comment: @PandaWood you are totally right, the string format is not realy usefull.

Answer (score 3):

You're overcomplicating it.

Just configure the desired batch size, do all the needed `Session.Delete` calls, and then commit your transaction.

NHibernate will execute `entitiesToDelete.Count() / batch size` queries.

Here's a code sample:

```
using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    foreach (var foo in session.Query<Foo>())
        session.Delete(foo);
    tx.Commit();
}
```

And a sample configuration:

```
var config = new Configuration();
config.SessionFactory()
      .Integrate.Using<MsSql2008Dialect>().Connected.Using("...")
      .BatchingQueries.Each(10);
```

(I'm setting an explicit value for batch size, but NH 3.2 defaults to 20 IIRC)

If there are cascaded collections, you need to make sure the deletes are handled by the DB.

You need to define the FKs as `ON DELETE CASCADE`, and let NH know about that:

```
<class name="Foo">
  <id ...>...</id>
  <bag name="Bars" inverse="true" cascade="all">
    <key column="FooId" on-delete="cascade" />
    <one-to-many class="Bar" />
  </bag>
</class>
<class name="Bar">
  <id ...>...</id>
  <many-to-one name="Foo" column="FooId" />
</class>
```

In this case, `Foo` has a collection of `Bars`, persisted to the `FooId` column.

Comment: Yes, it does (I've just verified it). As long as you are using a supported database and those entities were retrieved in the same session.

Comment: Does it matter if the object has collections and other related objects?

Comment: Maybe. You mentioned before that there were 200 statements for 100 deletes, so half of those might be collection deletes. If that's the case, I'll show you how to do FK-based cascade deletes.

Comment: Yes, that is the case Diego. What is the difference between FK based deletes and session.Delete(...)? How to do FK-based cascade deletes pls?

Comment: For me NHProf still shows that all DELETE statements are sent one by one into the database. I'm using NHibernate 3.2. I load 10 entities from the db and delete them inside same session inside transaction. My batchsize is 20.